# Best caching framework for asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, webforms

I have an order system developed on asp.net 4 web forms. I need to store order details (order object) for a user on the cache in order to manage it till I save it in the DB. 
I want to install my site at least on two server with option to scale for more in the future .
As you know , the two servers are located behind load balancer , so I need the cached order object to be shared on the both servers.

I hear about App fabric. 
Any recommendation to good frameworks to do that , Hope will be simple and easy to maintain one .
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/

Comment: Thanks. The problem is filling the order like wizard steps (5 steps) , the whole object will be ready for db in the last step . I mean cannot save it as is till last step du to other object relations .

Answer (score 1):

> I need to store order details (order object) for a user on the cache
>   in order to manage it till I save it in the DB.

If your data is not persisted, [SQL Server-based Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) state will work across machines on a per-user basis and can be configured with a minimum of fuss.

However, I would suggest regularly saving the order to your application database (not just the Session database) so that the user doesn't lose it. This is fairly standard practice on e-commerce sites. Unless the order process is very short, inevitably the user will want to pause and return, or accidentally close the browser, spill coffee into their computer, etc.

Either way, the database makes a good intermediate and/or permanent location for this data.